# How to use pivot wider?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, tidyr

I am currently trying to `pivot_wider` but am having some trouble. I have done `pivot_longer` before but going in the reverse seems more difficult.

[image]

In this picture I have the data frame on the top and want to get it to look like the bottom. I would post some code but frankly I have not really gotten anywhere :/

Comment: Please don't post data as images. Take a look at how to make a [great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for ways of showing data.

Comment: Welcome @Gregtt. You will need to further clarify the difficulty that you're having with pivoting wider in your post. Edit your post to show the code(s) that you're struggling with. Name the function that you're trying to use (and the package its from if it's not from base R).

Comment: In all likeliness, your question may have been answered in previous post on StackOverflow. E.g., there are plenty of posts about `reshape`, `tidyr::spread`, and `tidyr::pivot_wider`, as well as tutorial material on the web. I advise trying the tutorial examples first, then look through the most relevant SO posts. If you're still stuck, edit your post to clarify what seems to be the problem.

Comment: pivot_wider() requires a set of columns that uniquely identifies each observation. Your observations are not unique, so id_cols is defaulting to all columns.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you have in mind, but I guess there is something wrong about your desired output. One row might be missing there:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, 
              values_from = c(Time, Identifier, Box),
              names_glue = "{.value}{ID}")

# A tibble: 3 x 10
     id Time1 Time2 Time3 Identifier1 Identifier2 Identifier3  Box1  Box2  Box3
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    25    32    25 A22         A22         B23           123   123   123
2     2    27    23    27 A22         A22         B23           124   124   124
3     3    26    26    19 A22         A22         B23           125   125   125
```

Comment: Bravo Anoushiravan. I think the main clue is the `id` column?!

Comment: Yeah I think so. But not sure the output is what the op wanted.

Answer (score 1):

pivot_wider() requires a set of columns that uniquely identifies each observation. Your observations are not unique, so id_cols is defaulting to all columns.

You will need to create unique identified for each observation.
Since your screen shot of your desired outcome is not complete, hopefully this attempt will meet your goal.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
                 Time = c(25,27, 26, 32, 23, 26, 25, 27, 19), 
                 Identifier = c(rep('A22', 6), rep('B23', 3)), 
                 Box = c(123,124,125, 123,124,125, 123,124,125))

library(tidyverse)

dfWide <- df %>% 
  unite(idTime, ID, Time, sep = '_', remove = F) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID,
              values_from = Identifier:Box)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing sample data :)